# how do i loop through 2d arrays in python

Tags: python, list, loops

How would I loop through the contents of each nested list? I obviously can use for I in keywords, but that just prints the entire lists, sequentially. What I need to do, is loop through the contents of each list, before then moving on to the next list and looping through its contents.

```
keywords = [
    ["wet","water","soaked","liquid"],
    ["cracked","broken","smashed","snapped"],
    ["dead","charge","flat","turn on"]]

for i in keywords:
    print i
```

Comment: use 2 loops, second one over `i`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> keywords = [
...     ["wet","water","soaked","liquid"],
...     ["cracked","broken","smashed","snapped"],
...     ["dead","charge","flat","turn on"]]
>>> for i in keywords:
...    for content in i:
...      print content
```

Comment: thank you, that's perfect. I am a COMPLETE novice. could you explain how it is working? if I am correct, the first line loops through the nested lists, one at a time. for each list it finds, it then uses the second loop to loop though the contents of that list. then the print simply prints them sequentially??

Comment: yes exactly. 
"For works depend on the datatype. If you type for i in "Welcome": print i (This prints letter by letter) If you write the same with list of list, it prints single list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   for i in keywords:
        for j in i:
            print j
```

Comment: So I am able to nest loops inside loops?

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in keywords:
    for i in n:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can easily access elements of your list like this :

```
print keywords[0][0] // output : "wet"
```

if you need access element through looping you can write your code like this:

```
for i in range(len(keywords)):
    for j in range(len(keywords[i])):
        print keywords[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a generator

```
for i in (el for sublist in keywords for el in sublist):
    print(i)
```

or a list comprehension if you need to keep the results and don't care much about the format of the printout

```
unwound = [el for sublist in keywords for el in sublist]
print(unwound)
```

Comment: Thank you, but as a novice, I don't really understand how it works. But thanks!

Comment: yep, you NEED to learn about generators, comprehensions, iterators, iterables and the iteration protocol.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it:

```
keywords = [
    ["wet","water","soaked","liquid"],
    ["cracked","broken","smashed","snapped"],
    ["dead","charge","flat","turn on"]]

for i in range(0, len(keywords) ):
    print keywords[i]
    for kw in keywords[i]:
        print kw
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
print "\n".join([i for j in keywords for i in j])

wet       
water     
soaked    
liquid    
cracked   
broken    
smashed   
snapped   
dead      
charge    
flat      
turn on
```

**EDIT**

@Pynchia suggest to use `generator` instead of `list` like (IIUC):

```
print "\n".join(i for j in keywords for i in j)
```

And **timing**:

```
In [188]: %timeit "\n".join([i for j in l for i in j])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 us per loop

In [189]: %timeit "\n".join(i for j in l for i in j)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 us per loop
```

Comment: for the record: you do not need to build a list. A generator will do `print "\n".join(i for j in keywords for i in j)`

Comment: @Pynchia But `list` is faster... Take a look to the edited version

Comment: point taken and excellent solution. I just wanted to point out the possibility, language-wise.

Comment: If you removed the unnecessary parentheses around the generator, then it would actually look prettier than the list comprehension.